# need to extract specific text from the line

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I need to extract the specific variable from the line mentioned below , I have tried using sed to extract the variable but I am not sure the reason for missing the ing_month variable.

```
Script:

 echo "ing_year=2016,ing_month=03,ing_day=11" | sed 's/=.*,/,/g' | sed 's/=.*//g'
```

**Output required:**

ing_year,ing_month,ing_day

Please help me to understand or if any optimal command help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` regular expression will always match as much as possible.  If that's not what you want, make it match less.  A common arragement is to exclude the separator characters.

```
sed 's/=[^=,]*//g' <<<'ing_year=2016,ing_month=03,ing_day=11'
```

We replaced the regex "any character (except newline)" `.` with a character class matching any character except (newline or) `=` or `,`, thus constraining the range of the `*` quantifier.  Seeing as the fields always seem to contain numerical data, we could have constrained it even further to only match numbers: `[0-9]*`

If you want to perform multiple substitutions, you can combine them in a single `sed` script.

```
sed -e 's/a/b/' -e 's/c/d/'
```

(Not all `sed` dialects like the multiple `-e` options.  See your man page for details if this doesn't work out of the box.)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$ echo "ing_year=2016,ing_month=03,ing_day=11" | sed -r 's/([^=]+)=([^,]*)/\1/g'
ing_year,ing_month,ing_day
```

Break the data and apply globally.

Comment: At first I was confused and thought the OP wanted the values for each of the variables, but it seems that from the way it is written s/he  wants the variable names instead. I am using Windows 7 but I typed your first line in to the bash shell that is part of my git environment. And it gave the identical resultant line you have. And that's what the OP said s/he wanted. QED (and a point for you.)

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ echo "ing_year=2016,ing_month=03,ing_day=11" | 
  awk -F'[=,]' -v OFS=, '{print $1,$3,$5; print $2,$4,$6}'

ing_year,ing_month,ing_day
2016,03,11
```

this extracts both the keys and values in two separate row, delete the print statement for the one you don't need.